# Java produce version "1.1" in XML header with transformer

Tags: java, xml, version, domdocument, transformer-model

I want to produce xml files with 1.1 as version in the header, since i get SaxparserExceptions when parsing my xml-files with version 1.0:

```
"Character reference "&#3" is an invalid XML character".
```

When I manually change the header, i don't get any errors. Changing the version via outputkeys doesn't seem to work. The file has still the wrong header:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>"
```

example code:

```
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory
                .newTransformer();

        transformer.setOutputProperty(
                OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.1");
        transformer
                .setOutputProperty(
                        "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount",
                        "2");


        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(
                 "processed_.xml");
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: XML 1.1 is rarely seen in the wild - maybe you should rather fix your XML? Where does that strange "&#3" come from?

Comment: It it not possible for me to fix 'my' XML, since the content comes from a huge crawl dataset. It would take a while to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xalan probably doesn't support XML 1.1. Try Saxon instead.

Comment: That's it! Just needed to add a Saxon dependency in my Maven repo and then set `System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",    
          "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");` in my Java-Code.

Answer (score 0):

doc.setXmlVersion("1.1"); works for me.